# Is it possible to embed a download button within another app on iOS or Android -- without leaving the original app?

Tags: android, iphone, ios, mobile, ios4

Assume we have two apps.

Is it possible for app A to have a button that allows someone to download app B without leaving app A? (Of course, the user would need to click the download button and give consent.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes in android its possible but however you will need to know the name of the package of app B and use it to open the android market from app A so as to download app B .

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=APP B PACKAGE NAME (Ex:com.ex.ui)"));
startActivity(intent);
```

this will now open the market and take you to the particular application and you can download . Place this code within the click listener of the DOWNLOAD BUTTON .

Comment: To add to this, it's not possible in iOS.

Comment: Thanks! But this requires leaving app A, doesn't it?

Comment: In android any legal app download has to be done from the market . So you will have to open the market and download the application . However using the above approach on closing the market you will return to the application to where it was last halted(ie before hitting the download button) . So your app A is still present and facilitates accessing the market to download app B . You can also program app A to perform some action while the market is opened .